# Adding glib-2.0 support for Qt applications on Windows 7

Tags: qt, window, qt-creator, qmake, glib

I'm using Qt Creator 2.4.1 (Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)), running on Windows 7

How do I add glib-2.0 to my Qt Creator environment so that applications can find it by the line:

```
  PKGCONFIG += glib-2.0
```

in their .pro file?

I have downloaded the libglib-2.0-0.dll from http://www.gtk.org but 
where do i put the file in the `C:\QtSDK` structure ?

Comment: The DLL is only the runtime, you need to development packages (DLL + headers).  Check for 'dev' in http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php